# Cant start GitKraken - GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye

Tags: software-installation, crash

I installed GitKraken via Ubuntu Software center.

When I try to start it, it immediately crashes.
The Loading Animation starts, but it doesn't run smoothly. It only shows about three frames until it disappears.

When I start from console, I got this output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: undefined symbol: g_date_time_format_iso8601
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
state:  update-not-available
pci id for fd 30: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
pci id for fd 30: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
pci id for fd 29: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
pci id for fd 30: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
pci id for fd 28: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
pci id for fd 28: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
pci id for fd 28: 1002:15d8, driver (null)
[21086:0901/141402.659334:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
--2020-09-01 14:14:02--  https://crash.gitkraken.com/submit
Resolving crash.gitkraken.com (crash.gitkraken.com)... 174.46.225.159
Connecting to crash.gitkraken.com (crash.gitkraken.com)|174.46.225.159|:443... connected.

(gitkraken:21086): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:14:04.994: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.5: undefined symbol: g_get_language_names_with_category

(gitkraken:21086): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:14:04.995: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 40 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

/dev/fd/4                              0%[                                                                     ]       0  --.-KB/s               
Failed to get crash dump id./dev/fd/4                            100%[====================================================================>]      40  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

Report Id: 
bp-99308155-2943
--2020-09-01 14:14:11--  https://crash.gitkraken.com/submit
Resolving crash.gitkraken.com (crash.gitkraken.com)... 174.46.225.159
Connecting to crash.gitkraken.com (crash.gitkraken.com)|174.46.225.159|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 40 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

/dev/fd/4                              0%[                                                                     ]       0  --.-KB/s               
Failed to get crash dump id./dev/fd/4                            100%[====================================================================>]      40  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

Report Id: 
bp-f298d70f-107a
Illegal instruction
```

I have looked around online and tried to reinstall, but I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so I don't quite know where to start to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine started crashing today. I removed and resnapped but it still crashes. Installing the ubuntu .deb download from the gitkraken website worked.

Comment: I was about to post this exact solution. Just uninstalled my Ubuntu Software Store solution and installed via the .deb download from their site. That's all I did and it worked. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, so I reinstalled GitKraken from their [site](https://support.gitkraken.com/how-to-install/) (first time I installed it using Ubuntu Software). Surprisingly, the problem has gone. Hope this helped you, let me know if it worked for you!